# I would like to parse string to objet in c# micro framework

Tags: c#

I need to parse this string

```
"+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+420731177370\",\"\",\"2015/03/21 11:26:10+04\""
```

and I would like to parse for

```
id = 1, number = +420731177370, date = 2015/03/21 11:26:10+04\
```

Could you please help me how to do it without Regex because I have got an old version of micro framework.
My code is

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string[] test = sentences[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 1; j < test.Length; j++)
            { 
                //to do stuff
            }
        }
```

to do stuff where i need to replace \"xxxxx\" to xxxx

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: Basically you´d need a combination of `String.Split` and `String.IndexOf`

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < sentences.Length; i += 2)
            {
                string[] test = sentences[i].Split(',');
                for (int j = 0; j < test.Length; j++)
                {
                    test[j].Trim(new char[] {'\\','"'});
                }
            }    my code is like this but I am not sure how to trim the string by '\' and '"'

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29232584/edit) to include any new information (such as code) - it can be overlooked in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will point you in the right direction. Just be aware that while the code below works well for the string in your original post, should that string change it **might** not work as well since it's relying on character counts as opposed to regexes.

```
var Source = "+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+420731177370\",\"\",\"2015/03/21 11:26:10+04\"";

var SplitSource = Source.Split(',');

String ID = SplitSource[0].ToString().Remove(0, 6); //good

String Number = SplitSource[2].Replace("\"", ""); //good

String Date = SplitSource[4].Replace("\"", ""); //good
```

Comment: I had a wrong version of microframework, your solution works, thank you